# C# List<T>.Sort - why does default implementation have such good performance?

Tags: c#, sorting

Time difference between two overloads of `List<T>.Sort(...)`.

```
        List<int> list = new List<int>();
        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 20_000_000; i++)
        {
            list.Add(rand.Next());
        }

        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();

        //list.Sort(); // 1.77 sec
        list.Sort((n1, n2) => n1.CompareTo(n2)); // 5.80 sec

        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
```

Why is the second form so much slower?

Comment: You are comparing 50 million items with 50 million items so you are doing the square of 50 million comparisons.

Comment: @jdweng the sort algorithm used has time complexity n log(n), not n^2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`list.Sort()` will eventually call [`Array.Sort`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,1750), which has specific optimisations for when a comparer is **not** passed in.

This is discussed in this [blog post](https://mfranc.com/blog/net-internals-sorting-part2/):

> The core of sorting in .NET is an external native function called
>   TrySZSort. Under the hood Array.Sort calls C++ code that is part of
>   the CLR itself. This code is heavily optimized.

When you use the `list.Sort((n1, n2) => n1.CompareTo(n2))` form you lose this heavily optimised implementation:

> It is also worth noting that TrySZSort is called only for default
>   comparer. If you provide custom Comparer it won’t be used. For custom
>   Comparers, similar sorting algorithm as the one in TrySZSort is
>   executed inside managed code. This, of course, lacks all the benefits
>   of unmanaged code and misses most of the native optimizations.